# Elixir - Save with different file paths on Linux and Windows

Tags: elixir

I have a project that is developed on Linux but for production the release is compiled and built on a Windows machine and then transferred to a Windows server.

On my Linux machine I do like this

```
path = "pdf/#{item.id}.pdf"
File.cp(upload.path, path)
```

but on Windows that would be

```
path = "pdf\#{item.id}.pdf"
File.cp(upload.path, path)
```

Is there a way to write for both those cases?

Comment: You can use the :`/` on Windows too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Path.join/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Path.html#join/2):

```
path = Path.join("pdf", "#{item.id}.pdf")
```